# Reduce the size of my JSON query due to performance issues

Tags: php, json, phalcon

I have a controller in a Phalcon application that returns a JSON array of data. There are about 16,000 records that are returned at the moment, with each record containing about 5 fields.

Using Firebug, I can see that the controller itself starts returning data after only a few seconds, however the receiving portion of the request is taking 13 seconds. The data itself comes in at 11MB

Is there anything I can do about this? Is there a way to compress the data before sending? How about encode it in some other format that doesn't use as much data (I don't know alot about encoding but I believe it is encoded in UTF-8).

Comment: You can gzip it if the client does support gzip. Or let the client filter your JSON go get only the relevant data back instead of all the 16'000 records (if that is an option at all).

Comment: Pagination, perhaps?

Comment: I did think of that, however I am using jQuery DataTables which supposedly can handle much more data than that, so if I can return it all in one hit, implementation and usability is much nicer.

Comment: I don't think a human can handle so much information or find it useful...

Comment: @the_nuts- when it is contained in a searchable, sortable and group able table, it certainly is.

Comment: `jQuery.dataTables` cannot handle so  much data seamlessly. They can defer loading but many data are an issue for `dataTables` (have seen this issue in my projects with many data for dataTables)

Comment: @NikosM.- not the case for myself. I have tested this locally and have had well over 100,000 rows in the table with no real performance issues.

Comment: What sort of fields do you have. That sounds like a large amount of data for that result set size. If very large text fields perhaps returning portion of field limiting characters?

Comment: Cant's imagine using 100,000 rows at time. Displaying such an amount of data to just provide ability of sorting or grouping on jQuery is missing the purposes of SQL language you're probably using on backend. Provide users pagination of results (10, 30, 50, 100 per page) and add sorting/grouping features to your requests.